# Angular 2 routing removes URL path

Tags: angular

I added routing to my angular 2 app to read query parameters from the URL.  The URL looks something like `www.myapp.com/projectName/myPage.html?query1=firstName`.  In my routing code, I have:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routingComponent } from './app.adminPage';

// Route Configuration
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'myPage.html', component: routingComponent}
];


export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

My example is very simple, as all I am using routing for is reading query parameters from the page.  However, when I hit `www.myapp.com/projectName/myPage.html?query1=firstName` and it routes and serves my component, the URL changes to `www.myapp.com/projectName/`, which means that if the user refreshes, it loads back to my landing page.  I have another page that uses routing to ready query params that doesn't do this, so I am curious as to why this page does that.  Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: www.myapp.com/projectName/myPage.html it will navigate to your routing component since you didn't set any query parameters in routing if you navigate to www.myapp.com/projectName/myPage.html?query1=firstName it will redirect to projectName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const routes: Routes = [ { path: 'myPage/:query1', component: routingComponent} ];
```

set parameters in the path
now call the component using the URL 
www.myapp.com/projectName/myPage/firstname